# Google Analytics doesnt apply my filter

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I created a filter on my account.
This filter is a custom filter, search and replace. 
I use

- "Request URI" for Filter Field,
- \?.* for Search String

I also attached this filter to my specific view.

My problem is, if I go to the view->Reporting->Behavior->Site Content->All Pages, I see that the filter is not applied. I see pages such as "/xy.html?id=12345".

I would expect "/xy.html" only. Somewhere I've read that filters are not works for past data, but I did some test visits after I applied the filter and the urls wasn't changed :(

If I click on verify, I get this message: "This filter would not have changed your data. Either the filter configuration is incorrect, or the set of sampled data is too small."

Answer (score 0):

Your filter definition should use regular expressions for search&replace.

Search String: (.*)?(\?.*)

Replace String: \1

This will search for two parts: 1. all symbols before the very first "?" 2. all symbols after the first "?" in your URI.

The replacement will use the first part as replacement (all symbols before the very first "?"

Make sure you google some regex basics.

Filters only apply the new data collected, never the historic data you already have in your properties collected.